# Filling Internet Explorer Forms from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, autofill

I want to fill information onto the site 'select picker' section on the left side of the picture.

SITE
[image]

There is an element name 'picker' but it won't work.

[image]

The search bar is being completed using jQuery auto-complete which submits a form that navigates to an associate from the auto-complete box has been selected

I tried

`IE.Document.All("picker").Value = "Testing"`

`IE.Document.GetElementByID("pickerCtrl.currentPicker").Value = "Testing"`

`IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("input-group input-group-sm").Item(0).Value = "Testing"`

PS.
Is there way to just copy and paste the row at the current position where cursor is positioning at?

I can sendkeys tab 18 times to get to that specific search bar but do not know how to insert the entire row from my Excel sheet.

eg. `IE.Document.all("picker").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_1").Range("B" & intRow).Value`

I am completely new to this.

Comment: Is there an public url to test with?

Comment: No, unfortunately the site can be accessible only from company's laptop :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with example below may help to solve the issue.

```
Sub demo1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "D:\Backup20190913\tests\367.html"

    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    IE.Document.querySelector("[name='picker']").Value = "test value"

    Stop
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

HTML

```
<input class="form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched ng-dirty" ng-model="pickerCtrl.currentpicker" name="picker" type="text" typeahead="" typeahead-source="pickerCtrl.getpickerStrings()" ng-disabled="pickerCtrl.errorLoadingPickers || pickerCtrl.noPickerstrings" ng-hide="pickerCtrl.disableTypeahead" autocomplete="off">
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input but it did not work. I typed the same as you did from the above, getting an error msg 'Run-time error'-2147023170 (800706be)' Automation error THe remote procedure call failed.

Comment: Is there way to just copy and paste the row at the current position where cursor is positioning at? I mean I can sendkeys tab for 18 times to get to that specific search bar but do not know how to insert the entire row from my excel sheet... eg.IE.Document.all("picker").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_1").Range("B" & intRow).Value

Comment: You need to inform us, on which line you got the error. Also your logic is incorrect about passing the whole row of Excel. You need to loop through all the cells and set the value to corresponding element on the web page by looping the elements on the page. You cannot do that thing in 1 line of code. you need nested loop for this. Outer loop will loop through elements on web page. inner loop will loop through cells of the row.